# Google prettifier line slicing and white background

Tags: html, css, prettify, google-code-prettify

When I add line numbers with more than 4 digit numbers it's lines are sliced out of the code box.

When I use `background-color: #eee;` all works great but it works **not for white** colour `background-color: #fff;`.

1. **How to fix line numbers slicing out of the code box?**
2. **How to change all lines background to white?**

**P.S** White background has to be with line numbers :)

How it works right now (on picture: `linenums:320` with 3 digit number it sliced badly only in Safari`, for Chrome it starts slicing since 4 digit numbers). But maybe we can make some margin or something else.

[image]

```css
pre.prettyprint {
  background-color: #fff;
}
li.L0, li.L1, li.L2, li.L3, li.L4,
li.L5, li.L6, li.L7, li.L8, li.L9 {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<pre class="prettyprint linenums:3320">
def celsius_from_fahrenheit(temp):
    """
    Convert temperature value from Fahrenheit to Celsius.
    """
    return (temp - 32)*5.0 / 9.0

def fahrenheit_from_celsius(temp_fahrenheit):
    """
    Convert temperature value from Celsius to Fahrenheit.
    """
    return (temp_fahrenheit*9 + 160)
</pre>
```

Here is the example where you can check how it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/rwjbdayu/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that totally works for me. 
P.S Safari bad visualize google prettifier

```css
<style>
li.L0, li.L1, li.L2, li.L3, li.L4,
li.L5, li.L6, li.L7, li.L8, li.L9 
    {list-style-type: decimal !important; 
    background-color: #fff} 
</style>
```

```html
<div class="google-auto-placed ap_container" style="text-align: left; width: 46%; height: auto; clear: none; margin: auto;">
    <pre class="prettyprint linenums:3320">
        def celsius_from_fahrenheit(temp):
            """
            Convert temperature value from Fahrenheit to Celsius.
            """
            return (temp - 32)*5.0 / 9.0

        def fahrenheit_from_celsius(temp_fahrenheit):
            """
            Convert temperature value from Celsius to Fahrenheit.
            """
            return (temp_fahrenheit*9 + 160)
    </pre>
</div>
```